# GridSearchCV Kde choose bandwidth

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I see kde uses cross validation to solve for optimal bandwidth, but what does this one line of code mean `bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)`，why is the variable `bandwidths` that? Here is the [source](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html) `In [11]:`

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut

bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian'),
                    {'bandwidth': bandwidths},
                    cv=LeaveOneOut(len(x)))
grid.fit(x[:, None]);
```

help me

Answer (score 0):

The bandwidth is really a list of candidate values that will be tested. The output would be the best bandwidth to use for kde.